# getting order details from sales_order_save_commit_after event

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I am trying to get Product id and and product price from `<sales_order_save_commit_after event>`
Here's my Observer code

```
$order = $observer->getOrder();
$product_id=$order->getProductId();
$price=$order->getPrice();
  Mage::log($product_id, null, 'events.log', true);
    Mage::log($price, null, 'events.log', true);
```

But I am not getting any value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Product information are on order item:

```
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $_orderItem) { 
    $_product = $_orderItem->getProduct();
}
```

Comment: I did  this after your code $id = $_product->getProductId();
                Mage::log($id, null, 'events.log', true);
and still got null in log

Comment: `$id = $_product->getId()` or `$id  = $_orderItem->getProductId()`

Comment: i got  the productid thank youvery much but  I am also interested in price could you please tell me how to get price cause I tried this  $p = $_orderItem->getPriceId();
                $pp = $_orderItem->getProductPrice(); and didnt get the value

Comment: oh I got the price  turns outi used PriceId() ;